# Dynamically change the path of imported component in Angular 2 s

Tags: angular, angular-components

I want to change the path of imported component dynamically according to built environment.

Like when I am building my app with below command:

```
ng build --environment client1-testing --output-path ../dist/my-app
```

Then in app.module.ts I am importing a component like this:

```
import { ClientComponent } from './components/client1/client1.component';
```

I want to make the ClientComponent path dynamic like if I am building app for client1 then path should be

```
'./components/client1/client.component';
```

If I am building app for client2 then path should be

```
'./components/client2/client.component';
```

I am new to Angular so don't know how to implement it. We have separate folders for every client and want to import Components from those folders dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should consider looking at Dynamic Components as because AFAIK, you cannot change the component path based on the env variables in Angular.

What you can do is have a environment set up which will make a particular variable as true and then use it in creating a Dynamic Component like.

```
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  client1: true,
  client2:true
};
```

**Dynamic Component**

From here on it is a gist you have to use the data inside your Builder component to create a particular component for the client.

[More on How to create Dynamic Component](https://rahulrsingh09.github.io/AngularConcepts/dynamic)

Small Snippet from the Link

```
//pass data to this component like from any other component
<dynamic [componentData] = "componentData"></dynamic>

// Dynamic Logic 
import { Component, OnInit, Input, ViewChild, ViewContainerRef, ComponentFactoryResolver, ReflectiveInjector } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularService } from "app/shared/angular.service";

import { HelloWorldComponent } from 'app/dynamic-component/dynamic/hello-world-component';
import { WorldHelloComponent } from './world-hello-component';

@Component({
  selector: 'dynamic',
  entryComponents: [HelloWorldComponent, WorldHelloComponent],
  template: `<div #dynamicContainer></div>`
})
export class DynamicComponent implements OnInit{

  currentComponent = null;

  @ViewChild('dynamicContainer' , {read : ViewContainerRef}) decorator : ViewContainerRef;  // this is the container where we
  // we will load our dynamic component in short Represents a container where one or more Views can be attached.
  @Input() set componentData (data : {component: any , inputs :any}){ // getting the input from the called component which instantiates this component
    if (!data){
      return;
    }
    // Inputs need to be in the following format to be resolved properly
    let inputProviders = Object.keys(data.inputs).map((inputName) => {return {provide: inputName, useValue: data.inputs[inputName]};});
    let resolvedInputs = ReflectiveInjector.resolve(inputProviders);

    // We create an injector out of the data we want to pass down and this components injector
    let injector = ReflectiveInjector.fromResolvedProviders(resolvedInputs, this.decorator.parentInjector);

    // We create a factory out of the component we want to create
    let factory = this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory(data.component);

    // We create the component using the factory and the injector
    let component = factory.create(injector);
    //console.log(component.hostView);
    // We insert the component into the dom container
    this.decorator.insert(component.hostView);
    // We can destroy the old component is we like by calling destroy
    // keep this if you want only one instacne of the component as in this example else remove it and play around
    if (this.currentComponent) {
      this.currentComponent.destroy();
    }

    this.currentComponent = component;
    this.currentComponent.instance.ref = component; // this method passes the ref of the component to the dynamic component which helps 
    //us to destroy the component at will

  }


  constructor(private resolver : ComponentFactoryResolver) {}

  ngOnInit() {

  }
```